# Resolve root relative URLs when webapp is deployed to non-empty path

Tags: http, url, nginx, reverse-proxy

A webapp uses URLs of the form **/images/image1.png**, i.e. starting with a **/**.

The webapp should be deployed to a URL of the form **http://myhost.example.org/webapp**, i.e. the path part of the URL is not empty.

In a default setup the browser would try to get the image from **http://myhost.example.org/images/image1.png** and fail. What options do exist to make the browser resolve to **http://myhost.example.org/webapp/images/image1.png** without changing anything in the webapp?

I am using nodejs/keystonejs for the webapp and nginx as a reverse proxy.

Comment: The best solution is to use separate domain or subdomain. Second best is to fix webapp to be able to set root path. There is no other good ways.

Comment: Thank you! Used a subdomain.